# How to get the first element of IEnumerable (non-generic)?

Tags: c#

If I have a generic `IEnumerable<int>`. I can simply apply `ToList()` or `ToArray()` or `FirstOrDefault()` to it. How to apply these methods to a non-generic `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Attach code so we can help you better. AFAIK `IEnumerable<int>` is not generic

Comment: @wudzik IEnumerable<int> is the implementation of the IEnumerable<T> Interface which resides in the Generic namespace of System.Collections, thus it IS generic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have couple of options:

1. If you know that all objects in your enumerable are of the same type, you can cast it to the generic `IEnumerable<YourType>`. In worst case you can always use `object`:

   ```
   object first = enumerable.Cast<object>().First();
   ```
2. Or you can use enumerator, make one step and take current element:

   ```
   IEnumerator enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
   enumerator.MoveNext();
   object first = enumerator.Current;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. Follow the question that @Danier Gimenez suggested and make use of the `Cast<TResult>` method. After the cast you get a generic enumerable on which you can apply the `First()` method. This is also the most simple implementation.
2. Use the `GetEnumerator()` method which gives you an `IEnumerator`. And from here you can iterate over the collection. Starting with `MoveNext()`, you can use the `Current` property to get the first element.

**Edit:**
Andrei was ahead of me.

Answer (score 1):

it is simple
look this sample code

IEnumerable collection;
--- fill collection here---
collection.OfType().ToList() or collection.OfType().ToArray
collection.OfType().ToList() or collection.OfType().ToArray()
it's filter the (int/MyClass) types object and convert it to a list or array